# How to add and copy inputtext field with values dynamically

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a scenario in vf page where there will be a inputtext and an button name(Copy). When i will fill the inputtext field and click the button a new inputtext field will be created dynamically with the same value as in the first one.

I have tried below example which is working fine. But i need the values to also get copied.

Can anyone help me out in this.

Apex class -

```
public class addAttendee {
    public Account accounts;
    public Contact del;
    public List<Contact> addattendeeList { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> delattendeeList { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> attendeeList { get; set; }
    public Integer totalCount { get; set; }
    public Integer rowIndex { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> delAttendees { get; set; }

    public addAttendee(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

        accounts = (Account) controller.getRecord();
        attendeeList = [Select id, firstName, LastName, Email, Phone from Contact where AccountId = : accounts.Id];
        totalCount = attendeeList.size();

        delattendeeList = new List < Contact > ();
        delattendees = new List < Contact > ();
    }

    public void addRow() {
        addattendeeList = new List < Contact > ();
        attendeeList.add(new Contact(AccountId = accounts.Id));
    }

    public PageReference ave() {

        upsert attendeeList;
        delete delattendeeList;
        return (new ApexPages.StandardController(accounts)).view();
    }

    public void deleteRow() {

        rowIndex = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex'));
        System.debug('rowbe deleted ' + rowIndex);
        System.debug('rowm to be deleted ' + attendeeList[rowIndex]);
        del = attendeeList.remove(rowIndex);
        delattendeeList.add(del);

    }
}
```

VF Page -

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="addAttendee" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts" id="pb">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!0}" />
            <apex:pageblockSection columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable title="Contacts" var="acc" value="{!attendeeList}">

                    <apex:column headerValue="No." style="width:20px; text-align:center;" headerClass="centertext">
                        <apex:outputText value="{0}" style="text-align:center;">
                            <apex:param value="{!rowNumber+1}" />
                        </apex:outputText>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="First Name">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!acc.FirstName}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!acc.LastName}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Phone">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Phone}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Email}" />
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Action">
                        <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}" reRender="pb">
                            <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}" />
                        </apex:commandButton>
                        <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber+1}" />
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow}" value="Add Attendee" reRender="pb" />
            </apex:pageblockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!ave}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Regards

Comment: What part isn't working? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I filled up the fields in the vf page.. when i click add more button.. i need along with the values the field should get cloned..

Comment: Sid -- you should edit your post more carefully -- there is no button called `Copy` in your VF page; there is no button called `add more` in the VF page;  There is no inputText VF component in your VF page

Comment: May be you can use jquery to copy the contents to new field after it appears on the UI. just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a updated version of the code to copy the inputtext fields dynamically. I have used a javascript to copy the values to the last row from previous row. The script is inside `<apex:outputText rendered="{!isRerender}">` so that it will be called only after the row is added. I have used a different classnameto `addAttendee2`. Hope this helps.

**Controller**

```
public class addAttendee2 {
        public Account accounts;
        public Contact del;
        public List < Contact > addattendeeList {
                get;
                set;
        }
        public List < Contact > delattendeeList {
                get;
                set;
        }
        public List < Contact > attendeeList {
                get;
                set;
        }
        public Integer totalCount {
                get;
                set;
        }
        public Integer rowIndex {
                get;
                set;
        }

        public List < Contact > delAttendees {
                get;
                set;
        }
        public Boolean isRerender{
                get;
                set;
        }
        public addAttendee2(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

                isRerender = false;
                accounts = (Account) controller.getRecord();
                attendeeList = [Select id, firstName, LastName, Email, Phone from Contact where AccountId = : accounts.Id];
                totalCount = attendeeList.size();

                delattendeeList = new List < Contact > ();
                delattendees = new List < Contact > ();
        }

        public void addRow() {
                isRerender = true;
                addattendeeList = new List < Contact > ();
                attendeeList.add(new Contact(AccountId = accounts.Id));
        }

        public PageReference save() {
                isRerender = false;
                upsert attendeeList;
                delete delattendeeList;
                //return (new ApexPages.StandardController(accounts)).view();
                PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/addattendeepage');
                pageRef.getParameters().put('id',accounts.Id);
                return pageRef;

        }
        public void deleteRow() {

                rowIndex = Integer.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('rowIndex'));
                System.debug('rowbe deleted ' + rowIndex);
                System.debug('rowm to be deleted ' + attendeeList[rowIndex]);
                del = attendeeList.remove(rowIndex);
                delattendeeList.add(del);

        }
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="addAttendee2" sidebar="false">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
      .oddrow{background-color: #00FFFF; } 
      .evenrow{background-color: #7FFFD4; }        
      .textalign{text-align:center; } 
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function removeHighlight(elem){
        $(elem).removeClass('highlight');
    }  
  </script>
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts" id="pb">
      <apex:pageMessages />
      <apex:outputText rendered="{!isRerender}">
        <style type="text/css">.last{background-color: #FF0000; }</style>
      </apex:outputText>      
      <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!0}"/>
      <!--  <apex:pageblockSection columns="1"> -->
        <apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable" title="Contacts" var="acc" value="{!attendeeList}" rowClasses="oddrow,evenrow" onRowMouseOver="removeHighlight(this)">
          <apex:column headerValue="No." style="width:20px; text-align:center;" headerClass="centertext">
            <apex:outputText value="{0}" style="text-align:center;">
              <apex:param value="{!rowNumber+1}" />
            </apex:outputText>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="First Name" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.FirstName}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Last Name" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.LastName}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Phone" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Phone}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Email" >
            <apex:inputField value="{!acc.Email}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
            <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteRow}" reRender="pb">
              <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}"/>
            </apex:commandButton>
            <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber+1}"/>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      <!-- </apex:pageblockSection> -->
      <apex:commandButton action="{!addRow}" value="Add Attendee" reRender="pb"/>      
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:outputText rendered="{!isRerender}">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var table = document.getElementById('{!$Component.pb.thetable}');
            var lastRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
            var prevRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 2];
            var arrSourceInputs = prevRow.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var arrDestInputs = lastRow.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(var i in arrSourceInputs){
                if(arrSourceInputs[i].type == "text"){
                    arrDestInputs[i].value = arrSourceInputs[i].value; 
                }
            }
        </script> 
      </apex:outputText>           
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```